# Ignore inserting child entity if one of its columns is null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I Have two entities :

```
@Entity
public class Organization{
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)      
   List<Property> properties;
   ....
}


@Entity
public class Property{
   @Column("key")
   String key;
   @Column("value")
   String value;
   @ManyToOne
   Organization organization;
   ....
}
```

The point here property should not have a `NULL`, It's worthless to have a `NULL` value property.

So, Persisting Organization that has 3 properties one of them has `NULL` value will be non-sense to do so I want to ignore any `property` from being persisted cascadedly by parent if its `value` column is `NULL`.

So important note here I want all children to be persisted or updated only ones that have `NULL` value are ignored

Is there any annotation to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this ?http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete#Orphan_Removal_

Comment: but is not orphan removal practical in case of deleted parent the case here is different parent is still there I want to delete child that has `NULL` column value

Answer (score 0):

You can give a default value which again will be a null, because sql is going to put a null anyway

Comment: Don't get it, `value` columns is initialized with null already however persisting `new Child()` will create a record on DB

Comment: Oh now I get it, for that you have to do work in business logic to remove properties from list in organization, which are null. I don't think there is any annotation for this

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm trying to avoid doing business logic each time this entity is persisted or updated. I think so also that there is not support after few searches but I wanted to make sure of this.